# fetch data from database with condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, conditional-statements, fetch

I am working with python and PostgreSQL. I have this kind of data in a database:-(name,subname)

```
 ('Green Sq Choli', ['Green_Mehndi', 'Green_rasam M', 'Green_mahendi-2'])
 ('sakkarpara', ['yellow flaird', 'yellow embroidery sharara', 'yelo ZC', 'yellow flaird 
                  FBA', 'Sakkarpara Free'])
 ('MLT-RED', ['mlt-red'])
 ('MLT-PNK-BLK', ['mlt-pnk-blk'])
 ('gown bhuri', ['Akansha XXL'])
 ('Red SQBlouse', ['r m blouse', 'red seqin', 'rh  blouse', 'red blouse', 'Red satari'])
 ('Bhuri net', ['bhoori PPL', 'bhoorki', 'bhuri shrrara', 'Bhoori XL', 'Purple sharara 
                  bhuri', 'Bhuri PPL', 'Bhurii', 'Bhoorii shraraa'])
 ('Spara-XL', ['skkarpara-XL', 'YLW zc XL', 'Daya XL\t', 'Daya XL', 's-para-XL'])
 ('GHERA-M', ['\tGhera-M', 'Ghera-M', 'GHERA-M', 'ghera M'])
 ('Perali-XXL', ['peralisis-XXL'])
 ('Kinjal-xxl', ['kinjal -XXL'])
```

and I want the **name** of subname that have **"red seqin"** in their list elements

```
 cursor.execute('''select name from products where subname[0:-1]="red seqin" ''')
 email_record = cursor.fetchall()
 for row in email_record:
     print(row)
```

**subname[0:-1]="red seqin"** it's meaningless but I want data like this.

Comment: So what data type is the `subname` column? The square brackets could indicate JSON array, but the values shown are invalid JSON.

Comment: Yes, column have **character varying** datatype and **{"m blause","black seqin","black blouse","Blk satari","BLK Seq."}** this kind of data

Comment: However, `{"m blause",...}` looks like a native Postgres **array**. E.g. a column defined as `text[]` or `character varying[]`, not a `character varying`

Comment: So there is any way to find out the name

Comment: So what **is** the data type of the column?

Comment: column  have **CHARACTER VARYING**  datatype